# Is it possible to remove all other Gmail labels within a single label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I currently have filters setup so that all emails from DMARC end up in my "DMARC" label. I manage multiple domains, and every email sent to a particular domain also is filtered to have the domain name as a label.

The problem is that my DMARC emails also get tagged with the domain labels (two tags), and that is a huge pain for organization.

Is there any way to remove all other labels aside from the DMARC one automatically? For example, if an email is filtered to a DMARC label, no other labels can be attached to it?

I wasn't able to find a default way to do this in Gmail and really hoping someone here can help, as I'm not a programmer.

Many thanks!

Comment: Anybody? Any insights would be helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have two potential questions:

1. How do I **remove** labels for emails that also have a DEMARC label?
2. How do I **prevent** the domain-based labels from being attached for DEMARC-labelled emails?

I'll answer each.

1. This is easy. Just click on the DMARC label at the left-side navigation to view all those emails. Select all of them, then click the label icon and de-select any domain-based labels. Click Apply. Done.
2. You can't prevent labels from being attached generally, but you can ensure your own filters don't apply the labels. Revise your filters that label with domain names, to prevent them from being applied to DEMARC.

For example, you might have a filter that applies a domain label when:
"from:domain.com"

Let's say that the DEMARC label gets applied with a filter:

"subject:demarc"

Then, revise the domain filter to apply only when:

"from:domain.com -subject:demarc"